# Expression too complex for IIS Url rewrite in windows server 2019

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I have a rule that works well in IIS 8.5 included in Windows Server 2012 R2, but in IIS 10.0 Windows server 2019 give me an error that say:

HTTP Error 500 The expression ... failed to match because it was too complex.

the rule in short captures 6 parameters of a url, each of which is optional and can be of any value (only letter and numbers, for example:

http://www.example.com/aaa1/bbb2/ccc3/ddd4/eee5/fff6

rewrite in:

http://www.example.com/example.com/Prj/aaa1.asp?gsPar001=aaa1&gsPar002=bbb2&gsPar003=ccc3&gsPar004=ddd4&gsPar005=eee5&gsPar006=fff6

but if I have 1-5 parameters missing the rule have to match again, only the first parameter /aaa1 is mandatory.

This is the rule:

```
<rule name="Url_Rwr" enabled="true">
    <match url="([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)\/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)\/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)\/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)\/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
             <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?([^/]+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/{C:2}/Prj/{R:1}.asp?gsPar001={R:1}&amp;gsPar002={R:2}&amp;gsPar003={R:3}&amp;gsPar004={R:4}&amp;gsPar005={R:5}&amp;gsPar006={R:6}" />
</rule>
```

just for knowledge if I write a shorter rule it works correctly:

```
           <rule name="Url_Rwr_3PAR" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)\/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?([^/]+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/{C:2}/Prj/{R:1}.asp?gsPar001={R:1}&amp;gsPar002={R:2}&amp;gsPar003={R:3}" />
            </rule>
```

Any Suggestion? is it a bug?

**UPDATE:**
I've found a more specific things about the problem.

If I have a simple url the rule works well without error for example:
http://www.example.com/aaa1/bbb2/ccc3/ddd4/eee5/fff6

If i have e more complex url like this one:
http://www.example.com/print-preview/4113405466783653653534728581189576/sismabonus-110-and-change-of-destination-of-use

give error 500.50 The expression "([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)" failed to match because it was too complex

So is related to something like the numbers and length of parameter.

Comment: I tried your rule at my side which is working correctly without any issue. check this failed request log [image](https://i.imgur.com/YhNn9YR.png). instead of ([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+) pattern you could try this ([^/]+). set stopProcessing="true" in rule <rule name="Url_Rwr" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">. clear browser history and try again.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Have you read the "UPDATE" section of my question? Anyway I tried ([^/]+) and stopProcessing="true" but the error comes again.

Comment: with this pattern "([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-])/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-])/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-])/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-])/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)" i got the same error on http://www.example.com/print-preview/4113405466783653653534728581189576/sismabonus-110-and-change-of-destination-of-use. after changing pattern "([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)" it is working properly. check this image: [image](https://imgur.com/a/jUVKvFF)do not forget to clear browser history

Comment: Yes... but I need to capture 6 parameter because sometimes the url is 3: /print-preview/4113405466783653653534728581189576/sismabonus-110-and-change-of-destination-of-use    BUT sometimes is 6: /print-preview/4113405466783653653534728581189576/sismabonus-110-and-change-of-destination-of-use/4/5/6

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two rules one is to handle the 3 folders and another for the 6 folder path.

```
<rule name="Url_Rwr3" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?([^/]+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/{C:2}/Prj/{R:1}.asp?gsPar001={R:1}&amp;gsPar002={R:2}&amp;gsPar003={R:3}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

[image]

```
 <rule name="Url_Rwr6" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?([^/]+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/{C:2}/Prj/{R:1}.asp?gsPar001={R:1}&amp;amp;gsPar002={R:2}&amp;amp;gsPar003={R:3}&amp;amp;gsPar004={R:4}&amp;amp;gsPar005={R:5}&amp;amp;gsPar006={R:6}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

[image]

Comment: This is only a workaorund... cause I have to create one rule for 3, one rule for 4, one rule for 5, one rule for 6 and the rule for 6 goes in error...

Comment: @ValB you have to create different rules when your destination is different. as you said with 3 folders you will pass 3 parameters, with 6 you will pass 6. so you have to create different rules for that.